# Why is my php script not showing all data from mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php script that should change the TeamSpeak group of specific users.
For getting a bit visual aspect I added a table, so I can see what for users should get the groups.

My whole php script:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Berlin");

require ("config.php");
require ("groups.php");
include ("datenbank.php");

require_once("libraries/TeamSpeak3/TeamSpeak3.php");

$ts3_VirtualServer = TeamSpeak3::factory("serverquery://" . $cfg["user"] . ":" . $cfg["pass"] . "@" . $cfg["host"] . ":" . $cfg["query"] . "/?server_port=9987");


$user_check_confirmed = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE TSUUIDconfirmed = '1'";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $user_check_confirmed);



if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      if($row['MainSteamGroup'] == '1' || $row['vip'] == '1'){

            echo '<table border="1">';
                            echo '<thead>';
                                echo '<tr class="table-head">';
                                    echo '<th class="column1">Username</th>';
                                    echo '<th class="column2">Rocket League</th>';
                                    echo '<th class="column3">CS:GO</th>';
                                    echo '<th class="column1">FACEIT</th>';
                                echo '</tr>';
                            echo '</thead>';
                            echo '<tbody>';
              while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo "<tr>";
                  echo '<td class="column1">' . $fetch['Username'] . '</td>';
                  echo '<td class="column2">' . $fetch['RLHighestRank'] . '</td>';
                  echo '<td class="column3">' . $fetch['CSGOMM'] . '</td>';
                  echo '<td class="column1">' . $fetch['FACEITLVL'] . '</td>';
                echo "</tr>";
              }
              echo '</tbody>';
                        echo '</table>';
            echo '<br><br><br>';
        // Rocket League
        if($row['RLHighestRank'] == 'none'){
        } else {
            if($row) {
                if($row['RLHighestRank'] == $row['RLHighestRankSet']){
                }
            }
            if($row) {
                if($row['RLHighestRank'] !== $row['RLHighestRankSet'] && $row['RLHighestRankSet'] !== '0' && strpos($row['activeranks'], 'Rocket League') !== false){
                  try {
                    $client = $ts3_VirtualServer->clientFindDb($row['TeamSpeakUUID'], true);
                      if( $ts3_VirtualServer->serverGroupClientDel($rl[$row['RLHighestRankSet']], $client[0]));
                      if( $ts3_VirtualServer->serverGroupClientAdd($rl[$row['RLHighestRank']], $client[0]));
                      $sql = "UPDATE Users SET RLHighestRankSet='".$row['RLHighestRank']."' WHERE TeamSpeakUUID='".$row['TeamSpeakUUID']."'";
                        if ($db->query($sql) === TRUE) { }
                      } catch(Exception $e) {
                          echo "<br>" . $row['Username'] . " Fehler!<br/>ErrorID: <b>". $e->getCode() ."</b>; [RocketLeague1] Error Message: <b>". $e->getMessage() ."</b><br>;";
                      }
                  }
                }
            if($row) {
            if($row['RLHighestRankSet'] == '0' && strpos($row['activeranks'], 'Rocket League') !== false ){
              try {
                $client = $ts3_VirtualServer->clientFindDb($row['TeamSpeakUUID'], true);
                  if( $ts3_VirtualServer->serverGroupClientAdd($rl[$row['RLHighestRank']], $client[0]));
                  $sql = "UPDATE Users SET RLHighestRankSet='".$row['RLHighestRank']."' WHERE TeamSpeakUUID='".$row['TeamSpeakUUID']."'";
                    if ($db->query($sql) === TRUE) { }
                  } catch(Exception $e) {
                      echo "<br>" . $row['Username'] . " Fehler!<br/>ErrorID: <b>". $e->getCode() ."</b>; [RocketLeague2] Error Message: <b>". $e->getMessage() ."</b><br>;";
                  }
            }
          }
       }

    }
  }
```

For testing I set every user in the db as "vip". Overall I have 8 users, so all the users **should** get their rank.

If I open the php site now, I see 4 users in den table and the others are getting the rank updated, so why is my script not working how it should like?
I mean, every user have like the same database entry, the only things that differs are the names and their ranks...

Comment: Please add error management to your code. So you can see, what is wrong.

Comment: Well by fetching the first row and the outputting only a table header you will have LOST at least one of the resultset rows

Comment: ___DEBUG STEP 1___ Run `SELECT * FROM Users WHERE TSUUIDconfirmed = '1'` in **`phpMyAdmin`** and see how many rows are returned

Comment: `var_dump(mysqli_num_rows($result))` gives what? You are open to SQL injections, parameterize your queries.

Comment: Why all the nonsense code like `if ($db->query($sql) === TRUE) { }` and `if($row['RLHighestRank'] == 'none'){
        } else {`

Comment: So at first I forgot that three users didn't confirmed ther UUID, so there was a '0' - my fault. For now I changed my script so there is only one while($row...) left, thanks for that @RiggsFolly. And I have no idea why I have the nonsense code there, just copied it from one of my first php scripts I ever built. Kind of new in this :D

Answer (score 1):

The structure here is a little difficult to grasp. Can you show some example data?

You have a duplicate while loop which will likely cause an issue. I had a little cleanup which might be worth running:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Berlin");

require("config.php");
require("groups.php");
include("datenbank.php");

require_once("libraries/TeamSpeak3/TeamSpeak3.php");

$ts3_VirtualServer = TeamSpeak3::factory("serverquery://" . $cfg["user"] . ":" . $cfg["pass"] . "@" . $cfg["host"] . ":" . $cfg["query"] . "/?server_port=9987");


$user_check_confirmed = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE TSUUIDconfirmed = '1'";
$result               = mysqli_query($db, $user_check_confirmed);


if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    echo '<table border="1">';
    echo '<thead>';
    echo '<tr class="table-head">';
    echo '<th class="column1">Username</th>';
    echo '<th class="column2">Rocket League</th>';
    echo '<th class="column3">CS:GO</th>';
    echo '<th class="column1">FACEIT</th>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</thead>';
    echo '<tbody>';

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        echo "<tr>";
        echo '<td class="column1">' . $fetch['Username'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td class="column2">' . $fetch['RLHighestRank'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td class="column3">' . $fetch['CSGOMM'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td class="column1">' . $fetch['FACEITLVL'] . '</td>';
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo '</tbody>';
    echo '</table>';
    echo '<br><br><br>';
// Rocket League
    if (isset($row['RLHighestRank']) && $row['RLHighestRank'] != 'none') {

        if ($row['RLHighestRank'] !== $row['RLHighestRankSet'] && $row['RLHighestRankSet'] !== '0' && strpos($row['activeranks'], 'Rocket League') !== false) {
            try {
                $client = $ts3_VirtualServer->clientFindDb($row['TeamSpeakUUID'], true);
                if ($ts3_VirtualServer->serverGroupClientDel($rl[$row['RLHighestRankSet']], $client[0])) ;
                if ($ts3_VirtualServer->serverGroupClientAdd($rl[$row['RLHighestRank']], $client[0])) ;
                $sql = "UPDATE Users SET RLHighestRankSet='" . $row['RLHighestRank'] . "' WHERE TeamSpeakUUID='" . $row['TeamSpeakUUID'] . "'";
                if ($db->query($sql) === true) {
                }
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                echo "<br>" . $row['Username'] . " Fehler!<br/>ErrorID: <b>" . $e->getCode() . "</b>; [RocketLeague1] Error Message: <b>" . $e->getMessage() . "</b><br>;";
            }
        }
        if ($row['RLHighestRankSet'] == '0' && strpos($row['activeranks'], 'Rocket League') !== false) {
            try {
                $client = $ts3_VirtualServer->clientFindDb($row['TeamSpeakUUID'], true);
                if ($ts3_VirtualServer->serverGroupClientAdd($rl[$row['RLHighestRank']], $client[0])) ;
                $sql = "UPDATE Users SET RLHighestRankSet='" . $row['RLHighestRank'] . "' WHERE TeamSpeakUUID='" . $row['TeamSpeakUUID'] . "'";
                if ($db->query($sql) === true) {
                }
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                echo "<br>" . $row['Username'] . " Fehler!<br/>ErrorID: <b>" . $e->getCode() . "</b>; [RocketLeague2] Error Message: <b>" . $e->getMessage() . "</b><br>;";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That said, the conditions on this line in particular look quite complicated:

```
        if ($row['RLHighestRank'] !== $row['RLHighestRankSet'] && $row['RLHighestRankSet'] !== '0' && strpos($row['activeranks'], 'Rocket League') !== false) {
```

Seeing the accompanying data with anything sensitive removed will help further.

Comment: I think I managed to get it work now, because I only have one while($row... ) function now.

Thats looks complicated because I didn't understand the TeamSpeak php framework.
So if a users rank in ['RLHighestRank'] differs to the rank he got on the TeamSpeak ['RLHighestRankSet'], then it should change it to the RLHighestRank and also set the RLHighestRankSet to the actual rank he got on the TeamSpeak now.
Quite hard to understand but the easiest solution I found